# simple query design

Tags: mysql, sql, request, transpose

**simple query design help. this is my query:**

```
SELECT tkt.ticket_id, tkt.`number`, val.field_id, FF.name,    val.value 
FROM os_TICKET os, os_form_entry_values val, os_form_field FF 
where tkt.ticket_id = val.entry_id 
and val.field_id = FF.id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ticket_id   number  field_id    name        value   
5       592593         4        SSN         11111111111
5       592593         87       title       Mr
5       592593         117      dob         05/01/2011
5       592593         3        mobile      0091981123232
```

**i want to have the output like this:**

```
ticket_id  Number    SSN          Title   dob            mobile
5          592593    1111111111   Mr.    05/012011  009198182838485
```

Comment: Have a look at the `SELECT` part of your query.  You can see it's specifically selecting `ticket_id, number, field_id, name, value` in that order.  Have you tried changing your query to `SELECT ticket_id, number, ssn, title, dob, mobile` instead?  You will need to use the correct field names and maybe modify the rest of your query if those new fields are in a different table.  But give that a go and post back with your results if it still doesn't work.

Comment: the ssn, title and mobile details are in another table ... and they are linked by the ticket_id field.

Comment: This method of joining tables was in effect deprecated in 1995. Why not join the 21st century

Comment: @Strawberry please advise the 21st century join

Comment: Could you please post your database schema or a working http://www.sqlfiddle.com so we can test it?

Comment: @Calcolat thank you. i will try to send the schema

Answer (score 0):

If the name always have four value, you can try this

```
select ticket_id , Number, 
max(case when Name='SSN' then value end) as SSN ,
max(case when Name='Title' then value end) as Title ,
max(case when Name='dob' then value end) as dob ,
max(case when Name='mobile' then value end) as mobile 
from
( 
SELECT tkt.ticket_id, tkt.`number`, val.field_id, FF.name,    val.value 
FROM os_TICKET os, os_form_entry_values val, os_form_field FF 
where tkt.ticket_id = val.entry_id 
and val.field_id = FF.id 
) as t
group by ticket_id , Number
```

Comment: thank you so much sir. however the name field has about 60 values. so any help would be highly appreciated.